Getting null on cookie
I want to create a cookie :
@Path("/users")
@ApplicationScoped
public class UserResource {
    
    private final UserService userService;

    @Inject
    public UserResource(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    private String getDeviceName() {
        try {
            String deviceName = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
            return deviceName;
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            return "WEB";
        }
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/tsite-user/{id}")
    public Response retrieveBySiteUserId(Long id) {
        NewCookie cookie = new NewCookie.Builder("deviceName").value(getDeviceName()).path("/").httpOnly(true).build();
        try {
            var client = userService.retrieveBySiteUserId(id);
            return Response.ok(client).cookie(cookie).build();
        } catch (DataNotFoundException e) {
            Payload payload = new Payload("Error",e.getMessage());
            return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).cookie(cookie).entity(payload).build();
        }
    }
    ....
}

In another resource I want to retrieve the cookie value :
@Path("/notes")
@ApplicationScoped
public class NoteRessource {

    private final NoteService noteService;

    ...

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/pos/header")
    public Response createPosNoteEntete(TPosNoteEntete note, @CookieParam("deviceName") String cookieValue) {
        System.out.println("============== cookie = "+cookieValue);
        try {
            var newNote = noteService.createPosNoteEntete(note);
            return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED).entity(newNote).build();
        } catch (DataConstraintException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error occured during note creation." + e.getStackTrace());
            Payload payload = new Payload("Invalid payoad.",e.getMessage());
            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(payload).build();
        }
    }
    ...
}

At runtime it shows ============== cookie = null
So what is wrong ?
